# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name' when using SMOTE

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, oversampling, imblearn, smote

I am using imblearn over_sampling SMOTE technique in order to balance my imbalanced dataset.

Here is my sample code

```
import pandas as pd
dataset=pd.read_csv('E://IOT_Netlume//hourly_data.csv')
features= dataset.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4]]
target= dataset.iloc[:,[5]]
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

# applying SMOTE to our data and checking the class counts
resampled, yresampled = SMOTE(random_state=42).fit_resample(features, target)
```

so when ever i try to fit SMOTE model it shows me attribute error. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name' .Can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Also i have pip installed the library

> Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0 Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar
>   29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] NumPy 1.17.4 SciPy
>   1.3.2 Scikit-Learn 0.22
>   Above mentioned are the version installed.

features and target output
[features output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfJC1.png)
[target output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeuwH.png)

Comment: Could you please print features and target and show its output?

Comment: @Lakshmi-Intel i have edited my post check it out and help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imbalanced-learn 0.6 will accepts dataframe for `X` and series for `y`. However when writing

```py
target= dataset.iloc[:,[5]]
```

`target` will be a dataframe (2D) while imbalanced-learn expects a series (1D).
Just edit your code to get a series:

```py
target = dataset.iloc[:, 5]
```

Comment: We are probably going to be more explicit regarding the error message in the future. The reference issue is available there: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/666